# Is there a way to turn a VirtualBox image into an .iso?

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, iso

I'm in a bit of a pickle here; my main computer has trouble with the Nouveau open source driver for NVIDIA cards. As this problem is seemingly quite complicated, I was wondering if there was a way to add/install the NVIDIA driver from Jockey onto a Ubuntu/Kubuntu `.iso` file.

One possible way could be VirtualBox, but I don't even know if a VirtualBox image can be turned into an installable ISO.

I know Linux Mint comes prebundled with it, but I'd much prefer to stick to the Ubuntu line (what can I say? I happen to like appindicators and polish! :P)

Comment: Why would you want to do that. You can easily add to an existing .iso by loop mounting it

Comment: [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)'s an ubuntu wiki entry on how to customize a livecd, or you could use something like [remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/index.html) in virtualbox to build an installer of a custom system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an iso image from vdi file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556911/how-to-create-an-iso-image-from-vdi-file)

Comment: @karel are you trying to get this reopened to VTC as a dupe?  (i voted to reopen so you can)

Comment: @Fabby I can only report on my own personal experience which is that I was asked to VTR in order to VTC afterwards with a more accurate duplicate question. What happened when I accepted the request was the VTR worked and the subsequent VTC didn't. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be able to use [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/index.html) inside of a virtual machine to make an installer for that system.