# How to create an iso image from vdi file?

Tags: virtualbox, iso, custom-distributions, vdi

I have a `.vdi` file of OpenSUSE-13 in my host system Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Can I create a `.iso` image of OpenSUSE for installation, which contains all the applications in my vdi file?

The `.vdi` file is about 25GB in size and 11GB of that is the used space.

Comment: Not sure if Systemback runs in SUSE. Surely dd does. At this date, there are a number of possible solutions. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/18/vmware-v2p/#SysbackCompare

Answer (score 8):

From VirtualBox forums:

```
VBoxManage clonehd file.vdi output.iso --format RAW

dd if=output.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

Replace ***`X`*** in the above command with the letter of the drive you want to write to. Double check this since the command will destroy data on the designated drive.

Now it is on a bootable USB of whatever size.

Comment: The same forum says that the result is **not** an ISO file...

Comment: This answer says that it's not an ISO but that that doesn't matter. I've tried this in the past and forget whether it works. Other issues may occur, but I'll bet SUSE won't have problems: https://superuser.com/questions/114445/is-it-possible-to-convert-virtual-machines-to-physical-environments